# Why is the query for the scheduled query is running but not as Scheduled query in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query which will run if I simply run it through console or from code.

When I created `Scheduled Query` for the Query, it would not run. The Scheduled Query is successfully created, and the interval I set (every 2 hours) is correctly implemented but only the jobs are not created (I can see in Scheduled query that the time to run is being incremented by 2 hours every time it is supposed to run).

These are the properties when running query from Scheduled query:

```
Overwrite table, Processing location: US, Allow large results, Batch priority
```

If I do a `Schedule Backfill`, it creates 12 jobs which fails with an error messages similar to the following:

1. Exceeded CPU limit 125%
2. Exceeded memory

If I cancel all the created jobs and leave one to run, it would run successfully. The `Scheduled Query` itself would not create any jobs.

Comment: Are you creating the scheduled query in the console or through API/SDK?

Comment: Through console, @rmesteves. I found the answer though, I am currently writing the answer for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started the Scheduled query at 12:00 and made it to run for `every 2 hours` in `repeats`.

I assumed the jobs would run at the start time but apparently it is not the case. `Scheduled Query` ran perfectly as intended from 14:00 following with 16:00 and so on.

The errors regarding maximum CPU/memory usage is because the query I wrote had `ORDER BY` statement which was causing this issue. Removing that cleared the issue.

Comment: Please, accept your own answer to close the question